Black screen while using async operations in redirect GoRouter
I use GoRouter package for routing. I found a problem when I use async operations in redirect, a black screen appears after my native splash screen but before my main page.
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const InitialPage();
      },
      redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) async {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
        // here may be variables for verifying authentication, it's just an example
        return null;
      },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/main',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const MainPage();
      },
    ),
  ],
);

Are there any ways to get rid of this black screen, but use async/await?

There is no way currently to resolve this while still using an async redirection. You should be able to move that async logic into your existing page/route architecture, though, before triggering a navigation.

UPD One option is to use state management on the page, for example, flutter_bloc package
